# Is it possible to create in app purchase for local notifications in ios?

Tags: ipad, ios5, push-notification, in-app-purchase

I know it is not possible to charge for apns notifications. but Is it possible to create in app purchase that charge only once for local notifications in ios?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a common practice, I think there is no technical problem in doing it.